# How can I remove post title and post content in a WordPress post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove post title and post content field in a WordPress post. The placeholder for these fields are:

(placeholder: Add title) (placeholder: Start writing or type/ to chose a block)

Comment: This link will definitely work for you: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110427/remove-post-title-input-from-edit-page

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your function.php

```
add_action('admin_init', 'wpse_110427_hide_title');
function wpse_110427_hide_title() {
 if (current_user_can('subscriber'))
     remove_post_type_support('post', 'title');

}
```

This would hide title for the subscriber. Replace 'post' with your custom post type